# Game Center Leaderboard Score Removal

Tags: game-center, game-center-leaderboard

I have successfully created a leaderboard in gamecenter and it works fine. However, I would like to remove the score that I personally submitted there as a test.

After deleting the app and re loading it with Xcode, my high score is still in gamecenter! I don't know how to actually delete it.

How can I remove the score? Thanks :D

Answer (score 6, accepted):

To delete your test high scores from the leaderboard navigate to your [App's Game Center Page](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/LanguagesUtilities/Conceptual/iTunesConnectGameCenter_Guide/TestingYourApp/TestingYourApp.html) in ItunesConnect and click on Delete Test Data. It will take some time until the data will be deleted (according to Apple one day).

Regarding that Apple updated the UI of Itunes Connect compared to the documentation I add a Screenshot which describes the steps to delete your test data:

1. Go to your **Features** section of your App
2. Select **Game Center**
3. Click on **More** and then on **Clear test data** (delete test data)

[image: Delete Game Center Test Data]

Comment: Thanks Ronatory. I'll test this out :D Cheers

Comment: Hi ronatory. It took a while but your method worked. The scores have been deleted. Thanks for your help! Cheers :D

Comment: Welcome, great that I could help you . Cheers